# Is there any difference between object creation and initialization?

Tags: c#, oop

For example I have class `Abc` and I have created a default constructor for it.

What is difference between these two syntaxes?

```
Abc obj = new Abc();
```

and

```
new Abc();
```

Comment: They both effectively return a reference to the object. You just ignore the return in the second example. The constructor will still be called.

Answer (score 13):

The only difference is that the second holds no reference to the created object, so it will be eligible immediately for garbage collection.

The first will be eligible for GC only when "obj" <s>goes out of scope</s> is deemed by the GC to be no longer reachable.

---

**Edit**

It's hard to prove that there's really any difference between the two, as far as the OP goes.  Try running this program, you'll see that neither 1 nor 2 is GC'd.

```
class Program
{
    public class Abc
    {
        byte[] _bytes;
        bool _notify;

        public Abc(bool notify = false, int size = 10000000)
        {
            _notify = notify;
            _bytes = new byte[size];
            if (notify) Console.WriteLine("Constructor called");
        }

        ~Abc()
        {
            if (_notify) Console.WriteLine("***** Destructor called *****");
            else Console.Write("!");
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Destructor called");
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // type 1, hold reference
        Abc abc = new Abc(true, 100000000);

        // type 2, throw away
        new Abc(true, 100000000);

        int i = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            Console.Write(i++ + "...");

            // keep allocating memory so that GC will be forced ...
            new Abc();
        }
    }
}
```

Where you can see the difference if you assign `new Abc()` to a member variable, instead of in the local scope, for example:

```
public class Xyz
{
    Abc _abc;

    public Xyz()
    {
        new Abc(true, 100000000);
        Abc _abc = new Abc(true, 100000000);
    }
}
```

Now if you create an `Xyz` in `Main`, you'll see that the first `Abc` is GC'd, while the second is not.

Comment: As an aside, beware of side-effects! If you're thinking of causing global variables to be changed, other methods to be run, etc. as a side-effect of creating a new instance of your class, please don't. If you really want to get things done without relying on instances of classes, simply use a static class instead. I don't know if that is your purpose, but just wanted to be sure!

Comment: It's actually quite possible for an instance to be collected before its referencing variable goes out of scope in the source code.  See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cbrumme/archive/2003/04/19/51365.aspx for details.

Comment: Nitpicking: Actually the first will be eligible for GC as soon as it is no longer used, which may be much sooner than the end of the scope for the reference.

Comment: @BrianRasmussen right, I remember reading from Eric Lippert that GC will collect any object if it can "prove" that the object is no longer usable.

Answer (score 5):

They both initialize an object

```
abc obj = new abc();
```

Creates a new instance and assigns it to a variable

```
new abc();
```

This just creates a new instance, but doesn't assign.

You can use this, if you just want to call a method on the object

```
new abc().SomeMethod();
```

Which makes it eligible for GC once it has run it's method. But you should use static method calls for this (no reason to instantiate something and just throw it away)

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference. The first one you keep the return value in a variable.